# Appium : Is there a way to automate an app without having IPA?

Tags: java, ios, automation, appium

I am trying to automate a download app on iPhone , but I do not have the ipa (or app) file. The app is installed in the iphone. Is there a way to automate without the ipa file ?

Below is the desired capabilities. I like to know what do else do i need to add

```
     *DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.iphone();
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "My iPhone");
    capabilities.setCapability("udid", "1231412412412414"); 
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "11.3.1");
    capabilities.setCapability("xcodeOrgId", "10digitsCode");
    capabilities.setCapability("xcodeSigningId", "iPhone Developer");
    driver = new IOSDriver <> (new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);*
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to run app already installed on the device, you can use `bundleId` capability instead of `app` capability.

You can learn more about how to get the bundleId for an installed app, [here](https://help.swiftic.com/hc/en-us/articles/202916391-Find-Your-App-s-Bundle-ID).

Comment: I got the bundle id but through iTunes

Comment: So were you able to automate the app using bundle id?

Comment: Hi Wasiq , yes i did. Thanks!

Comment: It seem it can’t accept the answer. It may be the account is new. Will try again